# HTTPS over proxy doesn't work

Tags: c#, https, proxy, .net-4.5, webclient

I'm aware that there are tons of questions and answers on StackOverflow and all over the internet with exactly the same or very similar error message and I'm pretty sure I've read and tried 90% of them. I still can't get this fixed.

Below is the code with `WebClient`, as suggested by Visual Studio. But I also tried with `HttpWebRequest/WebRequest`, despite the warning that it's obsolete. No change, I got the same error: "**The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**".

Now here's the code. `makeProxy` is really just 3 lines, a new `WebProxy` plus the credentials for it. I believe it works because (a) if I provide a wrong credential there then I get an authentication error, (b) if I try to go to a http and not a https page, then I get it back, so I'm out on the internet.

```
protected string getToken() {
    string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domo_api_url_auth"];    
    WebClient c = new WebClient();
    c.Proxy = makeProxy();
    c.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domo_api_cid"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domo_api_pwd"]);
    c.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
    // ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
    // ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;

    Stream responseStream = c.OpenRead(url);
    return new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
}
```

My problem is that the message is not very helpful. I also tried to debug it, didn't help. I thought of the certificate on the site of the web service I'm trying to reach and went through the process of allowing that cert for W3SVC. Didn't help. And I get this same error for every https site, like google.com or stackoverflow.com or my own company's web site. But when I go to a random news site with http only, everything works fine.

The extremely suspicious thing is that it doesn't work even when I uncomment that first `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` line, and when I uncomment the second, supposedly redirecting the code to the validation, it literally never gets there. Like the validation wouldn't even start.

How to troubleshoot this? I don't even understand on which point of the web request-response process it fails.

Comment: Try adding all the flags (including TLS) to ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.  If you setup Windows to use the proxy does HTTPS in a browser work? - if it does look at the certificate and see if its the legit one issued to the site or a cert thats been inserted by the proxy server.  You can get highly detailed logs if you enable Tracing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same proxy on my laptop (where I'm also working on this) and https works everywhere, all browsers, all sites.

Comment: Ah, I don't believe this ... @AlexK. would you please add this as an answer? I'll accept as a solution.

Comment: Was it missing TLS?

Comment: Yes. Following another answer here on SO, I also tried setting SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 but TLS alone ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to activate TLS in addition to SSLv3:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
    SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```